# Function that converts a vector of numbers to a vector of standard units

Tags: r, normalization, mean, correlation, standard-deviation

Is there a function that given a vector of numbers, returns another vector with the standard units corresponding to each value?

where standard unit: how many SDs a value is + or - from the mean

Example:

```
 x <- c(1,3,4,5,7)    # note: mean = 4, sd = 2
 foo(x) 
 [1]  -1.5  -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.5
```

Is this fictitious "foo" function already included in a package?

Comment: Your sd=2 is a bit out... ;-)

Comment: note: in my example I'm using the complete population's SD (2), not the sample SD (2.23).

Comment: Ah, well then you should say so in your Q, because the `scale()` answers will only work if you do: `scale(x, center=4, scale=2)`.

Comment: @gavin: thanks for the useful clarification.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

yes, `scale()`:

```
x <- c(1,3,4,5,7)
scale(x)
```

Answer (score 12):

The function you are looking for is `scale`.

```
scale(x)


           [,1]
[1,] -1.3416408
[2,] -0.4472136
[3,]  0.0000000
[4,]  0.4472136
[5,]  1.3416408
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 4
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 2.236068
```

Note that the answers are not identical to what you posted in your question.  The reason is that the standard deviation in your x is actually 2.23, not 2.

```
sd(x)
[1] 2.236068
```

Answer (score 5):

How about simply `(x-mean(x))/sd(x)`, or am I missing some subtlety here?

Comment: i realize it's trivial; just wondering if it's part of a package given that getting this vector is an intermediate step in one of the most common ways to calculate the correlation

Comment: Why don't you just use `cor()`. Also, the correlation is by definition independent on linear transformations, so standardizing two variables first makes no difference.

Comment: Syntax should be: "(x - mean(x) ) / sd(x)" spaces are important (I was searching in the console like so ?x-mean)