# Can I calculate z-score with R?

Tags: r, normalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R, correlation: is there a func that converts a vector of nums to a vector of standard units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835545/r-correlation-is-there-a-func-that-converts-a-vector-of-nums-to-a-vector-of-sta)

By reading stackoverflow's comments, I found z-score maybe calculated with Python or perl, but I did not comes across any for R yet.  Did I miss it?  Is it possible to be done with R?

As (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score.)

```
z-score = (x-μ)/σ

x is a raw score to be standardized; 
μ is the mean of the population; 
σ is the standard deviation of the population.
```

I believe there are R packages designed for this?  Where can we found them? Or similar package for normalization?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148050/creating-z-scores http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835545/r-correlation-is-there-a-func-that-converts-a-vector-of-nums-to-a-vector-of-sta/5835599#5835599

Comment: Simon Blomberg: This is R. There is no if. Only how. -- `fortune("simon blomberg")`

Comment: why isn't `pnorm( x, μ, σ )` a solution?

Answer (score 71):

if `x` is a vector with raw scores then `scale(x)` is a vector with standardized scores.

Or manually: `(x-mean(x))/sd(x)`

Comment: how can I standardize a data per plot since I have multivariate time series data from many plots and I want to standardize per plot basis? i.e, I have plot, year and the measured variable (like abundance) and I want to standardize per plot basis! thanks!

Comment: Note: `scale` does `na.rm` internally, so it's more equivalent to `(x-mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))/sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)`